# Java simple program using the same variable for input - not working

Tags: java, string, variables, if-statement, java.util.scanner

All I want to do is use the string variable for all my scanner input.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);

String defaultInFile = "fileContainingEmails.txt";
String defaultOutFile = "copyPasteMyEmails.txt";

String myInFile;
String myOutFile;

    System.out.print("Enter input filename [default: " + defaultInFile + "]: ");
    //CRUD applications oh yea
    String myInputNom = getInput.nextLine();
    if (myInputNom.equals(""))
    {
        myInFile = defaultInFile;
    }
    else
    {   
        myInFile = myInputNom;
    }

    //System.out.println(defaultOutFile); THIS WORKS

    if (myInputNom.equals(""))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter output filename [default: " + defaultOutFile + "]: ");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("Enter output filename [default: " + myInFile + "]: ");
    }

    //System.out.println("'" + myInputNom + "'");        

    myInputNom = getInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println("'" + myInputNom + "'"); 

    if (myInputNom.equals(""))
    {
        myOutFile = defaultOutFile;
    }
    else
    {
        myOutFile = myInputNom;
    }

    System.out.println("Input file: " + myInFile);
    System.out.println("Output file: " + myOutFile);
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong? The second getInput.nextLine(); acts like it ignores all input.

I expect something in myOutFile, but I get nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect as output and what do you get?

Comment: There's just not enough information here. What is myInputNom equal to?

Comment: Thanks I added the expected output and myInputNom info

Comment: Where do  you write anything to the output file?

Comment: I don't want to write it anywhere, just display the default file name on the screen if the input is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine here.

```
% java -cp . foo
Enter input filename [default: fileContainingEmails.txt]: df
Enter output filename [default: df]: dfee
'dfee'
Input file: df
Output file: dfee
```

It's actually a relief to try to help, only to discover that nothing is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment:

> I don't want to write it anywhere, just display the default file name on the screen if the input is blank

is in error as your input file name will never be blank. If the user enters no text for the input file, it will be given the default value:

```
  if (myInputNom.equals("")) {
     System.out.print("Enter output filename [default: " + defaultOutFile + "]: ");
  } else {
     System.out.print("Enter output filename [default: " + myInFile + "]: ");
  }
```

So the if condition here:

```
  if (myInputNom.equals("")) {
     myOutFile = defaultOutFile;
  } else {
     myOutFile = myInputNom;
  }
```

will never be true.